# Black screen on Mate on Odroid

Tags: drivers, screen, mate

My old Samsung SyncMaster 205bw was black (no text, no interface)
with this fresh install of Ubuntu : ubuntu-20.04-5.4-mate-odroid-xu4-20210926.img

So I change config.ini with native resolution :

`setenv videoconfig "drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=edid/1680x1050.bin"`

and fail, so I try

`setenv videoconfig "drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=edid/1400x1050.bin"`

and it's ok but stretched (circles are ellipses).

I found this about my screen :
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_edid.c#L160 but don't know how to use this firmware :-(

note : this screen is in DVI with HDMI and it's OK on RPI4.

Comment: That is an odroid *respin* of a Ubuntu-MATE product; and not an official Ubuntu-MATE product.  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  FYI:  I believe the Ubuntu-MATE community will accept the question though - https://ubuntu-mate.community

Comment: Also asked at https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/black-screen-on-mate-on-odroid/25188/